# FullCalendar iOS UICollectionView

Tags: ios

Maybe this is not a real question, because I am asking for pointers on how to implement an Agenda (divided by months, week, day... something like fullcalendar plugin  for jQuery) in iOS. My first guess is to use UICollectionView and stylish every day of the agenda as a UIView.
Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UICollectionView` is a good idea.

However, it might take you a while, have you tried [searching cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar)?

Comment: Thanks. I think a good example is https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mscollectionviewcalendarlayout

Answer (score 1):

I've written my own view within a few days, you can borrow the code https://bitbucket.org/robvanderveer/calendardemo

It actually is a datepicker not a calendar. Mind that it is working code, but not polished.